# Can I store and access a "universal" variable in google apps?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jdbc

I have a series of google sheets reports that access my MSSQL Server database through jdbc. All of those reports each have a google app script (GAS) file with the credentials for my database. They all start somewhat like this:

```
var connectionName = 'server address';
var user = 'username';
var userPwd = 'password';
```

I recently started thinking about changing the password for that database, but that would imply in going through all the files and changing them manually. So I asked myself (and haven't found an answer yet): **"could I store a '*universal*' variable somewhere in the GAS suite and just reference it in my code?"**

Something along the lines of:

```
var connectionName = getVariable(serverAddress);
var user = getVariable(user);
var userPwd = getVariable(password);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a library to hold all the common variables.

Reference

- [Libraries | Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

Related

- [Design patterns for libraries in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13575942/1595451)
- [How to use Google Apps Script on any/all Spreadsheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16347213/1595451)

Comment: Beautiful. That seems just like what I'm looking for. Thank you, Rubén.